# results.vars in Ansible available only on the second start

Tags: automation, ansible

I want to put some rpm-packages in **"{{ playbook_dir }}/files/** directory and then copy and install these packages. As far as I understand I can reach it by using register.results variable. This is a part of my playbook:

```
- name: Copy packages
  copy: src={{ item }} dest=/root/
  with_fileglob:
- "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/*.rpm"
  register: my_pkgs
  loop_control:
    label: "Copy {{ item | basename }}"

- name: Install packages
  yum: name={{ item.path }} state=present
  with_items: "{{ my_pkgs.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "Install {{ item.path | basename }}"
```

On the first launch I get

```
TASK [my-role : Install packages] *******************************************************
fatal: [my-host]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has \
an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The \
error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'path'\n\nThe error appears to have \
been in '/root/ansible/test/roles/my-role/tasks/main.yml': line 9, column 3, but \
may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe \
offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Install packages\n  ^ here\n"}
```

but on the second

```
TASK [my-role : Install packages] *******************************************************
changed: [my-host] => (item=Install package1.rpm)
changed: [my-host] => (item=Install package2.rpm)
```

and I don't understand: am I missing something? Is it a bug or a feature?

UPD: ansible-2.3.1.0-1

@techraf was right: there is no `path` variable, but only on the first run. On the second run `path` variable is appear so I'll use `dest` for my case.

Comment: No one can tell but you. Please show the value of `my_pkgs`. Besides, I can't see `path` in the return values for `copy` module. There is a key callsd `dest`, but not `path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to register anything in your first task.  You can just use the same loop in both tasks.

```
- name: Copy packages
  copy: src={{ item }} dest=/root/
  with_fileglob:
  - "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/*.rpm"
  loop_control:
    label: "Copy {{ item | basename }}"

- name: Install packages
  yum: name=/root/{{ item | basename }} state=present
  with_fileglob:
  - "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/*.rpm"
  loop_control:
    label: "Install {{ item | basename }}"
```